# How i can select inner edges of selected faces in a mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges, faces, loop

I want to fill a mesh hole in a particular way that I’ve verified to rebuild a incomplete mesh, the steps I follow are:

- Select inner edges around the hole
- Apply *Bridge Edge Loops*

But I have a mode to select faces around the hole, then, how i can select the inner edges of this selected faces around the hole? or if you have any other idea to proceed.

Comment: If it's a contiguous loop of edges just Alt-click on one of the edges in Edge mode which should select the whole loop.